# iPhone Version 9.3.3. Newsfeed from Sky News showing annoying symbols

Tags: iphone

Why has Sky News in the News feed on my iPhone started to show annoying numbers and symbols in the text. (All the other news feeds are okay.) It looks like it might have something to do with computer commands for punctuation or something. (You can probably tell I'm not very tech savvy!)

[image: Example of corrupted Sky News feed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with how Sky News or Apple is formatting the text in their feed.  It has nothing to do with your iPhone, in case you were wondering.

I can't post a picture right now but so others understand what the problem is, in Apple News if you go to an article from Sky News, you'll see a mixture of text & symbols like `&#160;` in the article/headline.  It looks like these are some symbols or letters that are not being converted correctly.

Usually, these types of things get corrected fairly quickly.